# Java - Arrays - checking for duplicates in same input

Tags: java, arrays, duplicates

I'm trying to get the secret code from 1 - 40, not to repeat any numbers. How am I able to compare each of them and not get any duplicates?

I have extensively looked through Java documentation and asked my lectures and I can't get a working answer. I understand the concept, what I'm meant to do, but just can't get the coding right.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] secret = new int[5];
    //int[] secret = {0,0,0,0,0};
    int[][] num = new int[3][5];
    int correctL1 = 0;
    int correctL2 = 0;
    int correctL3 = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){ // to get secret numbers.
        secret[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * (40 - 1)) + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(secret));
}
```

I have tried putting this into the loop to get another number but it's still giving me duplicates.

```
if(((secret[i] == secret[0]) || (secret[i] == secret[1]) || 
    (secret[i] == secret[2]) || (secret[i] == secret[3]) ||
    (secret[i] == secret[4])) || (secret[i] != 0)) {

    secret[i] = ((int) ((Math.random() * (40 - 1)) + 1));
}
```

Comment: since Java is an **object oriented** language you should get used to OO approaches: Java has different Collection types. they roughly split into Lists, which support and order, `null` elements and duplicates, and Sets, which support uniqueness of elements. So the easieast approach is to collect the input data in an `HashSet`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java 8, you can use [`Random#ints`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-int-int-) to easily generate an array of distinct random numbers:

```
int[] secret = new Random().ints(1, 40).distinct().limit(5).toArray();
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/rgJ1P3)

Otherwise, you can generate a `Set<Integer>` by using a `while` loop:

```
Set<Integer> secret = new HashSet<>();
Random gen = new Random();
while (secret.size() < 5) {
    secret.add(gen.nextInt(40 - 1) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply use a `Set<Integer>` to keep the already generated numbers and iterate as long as the generated number is part of the generated numbers.

```
Set<Integer> existing = new HashSet<>();
for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){ // to get secret numbers.
    // Loop until the generated number is not part of the already generated numbers
    int value;
    do {
        value = (int) ((Math.random() * (40 - 1)) + 1);
    } while (!existing.add(value));
    secret[i] = value;
}
```

Comment: you can simplify with `while(existing.size() < 5) { existing.add(X); }`

Answer (score 2):

Why not creating a `Set<Integer>` (so you will not get any duplicate) and iterate until its size is 5 ?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Set Collection..for better performance you can use below code

```
Set<Integer> data=new HashSet<Integer>();
```

If you want to get all elements by ascending order,you can use TreeSet

OR Other Logic is Every collection has contains method which returns boolean for e.g.`data.contains(o)`

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){
        int[] secret = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // to get secret numbers.
            secret[i] = (int) ((Math.random() * (40 - 1)) + 1);
        }
        System.out.println("Array:" + Arrays.toString(secret));
        Set<Integer> mySet = new HashSet<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { // to get secret numbers.
            mySet.add(secret[i]);
        }
        if (mySet.size() == secret.length) {
            System.out.println("OK");
            break;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not ok");
        }
    }
```